PHP Error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
Looking to finish an e-commerce project, when I click on order button I get this error, any advice?
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (ecommerce_project.orders, CONSTRAINT orders_product_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE) (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into orders (name, rec_address, phone, user_id, product_id, updated_at, created_at) values (user, canada, 1525548, 1, 19, 2024-09-17 08:12:36, 2024-09-17 08:12:36))
Code:
throw new UniqueConstraintViolationException(
                    $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
                );
            }
 
            throw new QueryException(
                $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
            );
        }
    }
 
    /**
     * Determine if the given database exception was caused by a unique constraint violation.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return bool
     */


I assume orders_product_id_foreign should reference products (id) and not users (id). Can you include the migration for the orders table?

Edit your question & share the migration file for orders & users table

How do I share the migration file here, do these screenshots help by chance?
freeimage.host/i/d6hulgR
freeimage.host/i/d6huaqJ
freeimage.host/i/d6hu1Jp
freeimage.host/i/d6hu7sa

Looks like user_id from orders is not present in the users table which is why you can't insert the new order
